# Facebook SDK for Android request error

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I use Facebook SDK for Android 3.0
I want to get the user's photos and show in my app.
Reference document, login was a success.
and I try to get the album.

I tried two methods **fql** and **graph api**.

```
    graph_or_fql = "fql";
    if (graph_or_fql.equals("fql")) {
        String query = "SELECT aid, cover_pid, name, size, visible, object_id FROM album WHERE owner = "
                + userId;
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "fql.query");
        params.putString("query", query);

        mAsyncRunner.request(null, params,
                new PhotosRequestListener());
    } else {
//      Bundle params = new Bundle();
//      params.putString("fields", "name, aid, size");
//      mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params,
//              new PhotosRequestListener());
        mAsyncRunner.request("me/album",
                new PhotosRequestListener());
    }

    /*
     * callback after friends are fetched via me/friends or fql query.
     */
    public class PhotosRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("tag", "response: " + response);
            try {
                if (graph_or_fql.equals("fql")) {
                    jsonArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("data");
                    // jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    // JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    // jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.getString("data"));
                } else {
                    jsonArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("data");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                showToast("JSONError: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this));
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

But all error.

> fql error message: "error_msg":"Session key invalid or no longer valid"

```
11-07 16:41:10.956: D/tag(468): response: {"error_code":102,"error_msg":"Session key invalid or no longer valid","request_args":[{"key":"query","value":"SELECT aid, cover_pid, name, size, visible, object_id FROM album WHERE owner = 100001791736733"},{"key":"method","value":"fql.query"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
11-07 16:41:10.956: W/System.err(468): org.json.JSONException: No value for data
11-07 16:41:10.966: W/System.err(468):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
11-07 16:41:11.015: W/System.err(468):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
11-07 16:41:11.015: W/System.err(468):  at com.example.facebookphoto.MainActivity$PhotosRequestListener.onComplete(MainActivity.java:144)
11-07 16:41:11.015: W/System.err(468):  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:273)
```

> graph api error message: "error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}

```
11-07 16:45:43.106: D/tag(538): response: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
11-07 16:45:43.106: W/System.err(538): org.json.JSONException: No value for data
11-07 16:45:43.156: W/System.err(538):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
11-07 16:45:43.156: W/System.err(538):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
11-07 16:45:43.176: W/System.err(538):  at com.example.facebookphoto.MainActivity$PhotosRequestListener.onComplete(MainActivity.java:149)
11-07 16:45:43.176: W/System.err(538):  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:273)
```

I don't get it, because what causes.  help me, thanks.

Comment: the problem is not with the method you use to get the data, but it seems that you don't have valid access token. you have to create a Session object and open it, so that it gets/loads access token - that is before using the API